# SageMath: Why doesn't sagemath give line number in case of TypeErrors? Is there a way to trace the actual line number?

Tags: python, sage

Using Sagemath 9.2 on Windows 10

### `a.sage`

```
i = 10
print("hello " + i)
```

sage: load("a.sage")

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- TypeError      Traceback (most recent call last)
>  in 
> ----> 1 load("a.sage")
>
> /opt/sagemath-9.2/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sage/misc/persist.pyx
> in sage.misc.persist.load
> (build/cythonized/sage/misc/persist.c:2558)()
> 141
> 142     if sage.repl.load.is_loadable_filename(filename):
> --> 143         sage.repl.load.load(filename, globals())
> 144         return
> 145
>
> /opt/sagemath-9.2/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sage/repl/load.py
> in load(filename, globals, attach)
> 270                 add_attached_file(fpath)
> 271             with open(fpath) as f:
> --> 272                 exec(preparse_file(f.read()) + "\n", globals)
> 273     elif ext == '.spyx' or ext == '.pyx':
> 274         if attach:
>
> in
>
> /opt/sagemath-9.2/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sage/rings/integer.pyx
> in sage.rings.integer.Integer.**add**
> (build/cythonized/sage/rings/integer.c:12447)()    1785
> return y    1786
> -> 1787         return coercion_model.bin_op(left, right, operator.add)    1788    1789     cpdef *add*(self, right):
>
> /opt/sagemath-9.2/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sage/structure/coerce.pyx
> in sage.structure.coerce.CoercionModel.bin_op
> (build/cythonized/sage/structure/coerce.c:11304)()    1246         #
> We should really include the underlying error.    1247         # This
> causes so much headache.
> -> 1248         raise bin_op_exception(op, x, y)    1249    1250     cpdef canonical_coercion(self, x, y):
>
> **TypeError: unsupported operand parent(s) for +: '<class 'str'>' and**
> **'Integer Ring'**

In many other types of errors, sage math does give line number where the error happened, but usually in TypeErrors, I don't see that happening

So,

1. This is a big problem in longer programs & especially in more complicated datatypes. It's quite difficult to track the line giving the problem.
2. What the different kinds of errors where this happens?
3. Is there a simple way to track the line number (I use a rather long way).

Comment: If you use `%attach a.sage` instead, it will print line numbers. The line numbers are for the preparsed version of the file, but you can perhaps extract enough information from that.

Comment: @JohnPalmieri - attach is indeed better - `~/.sage/temp/DESKTOP-AEKPTOP/1082/a.saged6usi0r8.py in <module>
      5 _sage_const_10 = Integer(10)
      6 i = _sage_const_10
----> 7 print("hello " + i)
` - it gave me this

Comment: @JohnPalmieri - if you put your comment as answer, I can accept it.

Comment: [This issue is discussed in SageMath issue #22167](https://github.com/sagemath/sage/issues/22167).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `%attach a.sage` instead, it will print line numbers. The line numbers are for the preparsed version of the file, but you can perhaps extract enough information from that. Here is what I see:

```
sage: %attach /Users/palmieri/Desktop/a.sage                                                                               
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-a6e4524362f6> in <module>
----> 1 get_ipython().run_line_magic('attach', '/Users/palmieri/Desktop/a.sage')


  [snip]


~/.sage/temp/John-iMac-2017.local/34847/a.sage5dnlgxa9.py in <module>
      5 _sage_const_10 = Integer(10)
      6 i = _sage_const_10
----> 7 print("hello " + i)


  [snip]


TypeError: unsupported operand parent(s) for +: '<class 'str'>' and 'Integer Ring'
```

`%attach` also has the feature that whenever the file is changed, it automatically gets reloaded.

Comment: Remark: the issue mentioned at the start of the answer is a longstanding issue [SageMath #71](https://github.com/sagemath/sage/issues/71).